# Persisting pinia stores using nuxt 3

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3, pinia

I followed the guide available here [pinia persisted state plugin](https://prazdevs.github.io/pinia-plugin-persistedstate/frameworks/nuxt-3.html) but I can't get it to work, my states reset on page refresh, is there something wrong with my config?

```
// nuxt.config
modules: [
  [
    "@pinia/nuxt",
    {
      autoImports: ["defineStore", "acceptHMRUpdate"],
    },
  ],
   @pinia-plugin-persistedstate/nuxt",
],
```

```
// test-store
export const useTestStore = defineStore("test-store", {
  state: () => ({
    hello: "there"
  }),
  persist: {
    storage: persistedState.localStorage,
  }
});
```

On one page I call

```
const store = useTestStore();
store.$patch({ hello: "changed" });
```

and on another I console log the state

```
const store = useTestStore();
console.log(store.$state.hello);
```

when navigating from one to the other, instead of logging "changed" it logs "there".

Comment: does the state get saved correctly to your browser's [local storage](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/storage/localstorage/)? Use [vue devtools](https://devtools.vuejs.org/) and check the live state of your Pinia store. Does it display an updated value?

Comment: it doesn't but I've pinpointed that the issue is caused by another store that is being used inside a plugin, removed the pinia store usage from the plugin and now persist works

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues and decided to go for a quick and easy workaround, without using any plugins:

```
// app.vue

<template>
  <NuxtLayout>
    <NuxtPage />
  </NuxtLayout>
</template>

<script setup>
import { watch, onBeforeMount } from "vue";
import { usePersistentStore } from "~~/store/persistent";

const ps = usePersistentStore();

onBeforeMount(() => {
  ps.$state = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("persistent"));
});
watch(ps.$state, (value) => {
  localStorage.setItem("persistent", JSON.stringify(ps.$state));
});
</script>
```

Comment: I was using the store in a plugin, which causes the persist to not work, removing it worked https://github.com/prazdevs/pinia-plugin-persistedstate/issues/190